# What plugin can I use to create a list / slideshow of featured images?

Tags: plugins, media, post-thumbnails, uploads, slideshow

I'm looking for a plugin that will allow the user to upload files, maybe 4-10 that can be used on the homepage as part of a slideshow. I can code the slideshow part myself, if necessary, but the thing I'm interested in is a way for the user to select / upload the photos. It would be excellent if they were integrated with Wordpress' media manager just like other uploads. Thanks!

Comment: i can recommend u this one http://www.geovid.com/flash_slideVidShow/, it's great and simple

Comment: flash is a thing of the past and this thing just looks kind of sketchy anyhow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### jQuery [Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) and [Cycle Lite](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/lite/) are very flexible and very easy to use.

Most [WordPress slideshow plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=slideshow&sort=) either don't do exactly what you need or they try to do everything and are overly complicated with options and features.

***The solution***

Build the slideshow feature into your theme template or code your own plugin.

To make it easy and intuitive for the user I would create a "Featured Content" custom post type that only supports a featured image (thumbnail) and the excerpt if you want to add a caption to each image.

#### [Register your custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) and for the supports argument use:

```
 'supports' => array('thumbnail','excerpt',)
```

#### Enqueue your scripts in functions.php

```
<?php

    add_action( 'init', 'c3m_get_the_js' );

    function c3m_get_the_js() {
    wp_register_script( 'jquery.cycle', get_bloginfo('template_directory'). '/path_to_your_js/jquery.cycle.lite.1.1.min.js', array('jquery'), TRUE);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery.cycle' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom', get_bloginfo('template_directory'). '/path_to_your_js/c3m_functions.js', array('jquery.cycle'), TRUE);
            }

?>
```

#### Set your "featured image" size in functions.php

```
add_image_size( 'featured', 747, 285, true );
```

#### Set up the the template to display your slideshow

```
<div id="home-slider">

        <div class="cycle-nav">
            <a id="prev2" href="#">«Prev</a> <a id="next2" href="#">Next»</a>
        </div>

        <ul id="cycle" class="pics">

            <?php
                        $i = 1;
                        global $wp_query;
                        $custom_query = array(
                            'post_type' => 'featured_content',
                            'posts_per_page' => -1
                        );
                        if ( $custom_query )
                            query_posts( $custom_query );
                        $more = 0;
                    ?>
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <li class="cycle-item slide-<?php echo $i; ?>">

                 <?php   the_post_thumbnail('featured'); ?>
                <div class="excerpt">
                    <?php echo get_the_content('<span class="more">more &raquo;</span>'); //Use this if you want text with your images ?>
                </div>
            </li>

            <?php
                        $i++;
                        endwhile;
                        endif;
                    ?>
                    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

        </ul>

    </div> <!-- /home-slider -->
```

### Add your jQuery Cycle settings to your custom.js file

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


jQuery('ul#cycle').cycle({
            timeout: 9000,
            speed: 1500,
            delay: 2000,
            prev:   '#prev2',
            next:   '#next2'
        });
});
```

#### Add some css

```
     #home-slider {
width:735px;
     overflow:hidden;
     height:280px; 
    float:right; 
    position:relative;
     margin-right:0; 
    display:inline-block
}

    a#prev2 {
position:absolute; 
    width:31px; 
    height:32px; 
    text-indent:-999em; 
    z-index:100; 
    background-position:0 0; 
    background-image:url(images/cycle-nav.png); 
    top:185px; 
    box-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(2,2,2,0.3); 
    -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(2,2,2,0.3);  
    -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(2,2,2,0.3)
    }

    a#prev2:hover {
    background-position:0px -32px
    }

     a#next2 {
    position:absolute; 
    right:0px; 
    width:31px; 
    height:31px; 
    display:block; 
    z-index:100; 
    top:185px; 
    background-position:31px 0px; 
    background-image:url(images/cycle-nav.png); 
    overflow:hidden; 
    text-indent:-999em; 
    box-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(2,2,2,.3);  
    -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(2,2,2,0.3);  
    -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(2,2,2,0.3)
    }

     a#next2:hover {
    background-position:31px -32px
    }

    ul#cycle { 
    margin:0;  
    padding:0;  
    list-style:none
    }

    ul#cycle .excerpt {
    width:700px; 
    height:82px;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0); 
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.5); 
    position:absolute; bottom:0;
    padding:10px 20px 10px 25px; 
    overflow:hidden
    }
```

#### The UI

[image]

#### The Slider on the front end

[image]